# Application execution failed and not getting expected outcome

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am developing a simple spring boot application. I am creating a `LoginController` class and trying to access the API which is present in the `LoginController` class. I am able to execute the program, but not getting the expected output while I am trying to access the API.

## Login Controller

```
        package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.controller;

        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

        @RestController
        public class LoginController {

            @GetMapping("/login")
            public String loginMessage() {

                return "Welcome to Springboot Application";

            }

        }
```

## Bootstraping Application

```
        package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.springbootwebexample;

        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

        @SpringBootApplication
        public class SpringBootWebExampleApplication {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebExampleApplication.class, args);
            }

        }
```

## pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-web-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spring-boot-web-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> I run the project several times but don't get the output as expected. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation scans the current package and the sub-packages to look for `@Component`. In your case, `LoginController` is not in the package, not a sub-package of `SpringBootWebExampleApplication`.

- Either move `com.in28minutes.springboot.web.controller` in `com.in28minutes.springboot.web.springbootwebexample.controller`
- Or, use  `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "your.package")` on your `SpringBootWebExampleApplication`

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.springbootwebexample;

        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

        @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.in28minutes.springboot")
        public class SpringBootWebExampleApplication {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebExampleApplication.class, args);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.springbootwebexample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.in28minutes.springboot")
public class SpringBootWebExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```